# MouseOver tips are needed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, mouseover

Here is the problem:

- I have 2 buttons (let's call them `btn1` and `btn2` to simplify) and 2 `MovieClips` (`mc1` and `mc2`).
- I want to change my `MovieClips'` alpha when I hover the buttons, as if  I hover `btn1`, `mc1` becomes visible and when I hover `btn2`, I want `mc2` to become visible.
- `mc1` and `mc2` should remain invisible when none of the buttons is being hovered.

I tried this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

mc1.alpha=0;

btn1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, btn1over);
btn1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, btn1out);

function btn1over (e:MouseEvent):void {
    mc1.alpha=1;
    stop ();
}

function btn1out (e:MouseEvent):void {
    mc1.alpha=0;
    play ();
}
```

Pretty much the same for `btn2` and `mc2`. But it doesn't seem to work: no stop event happens, no alpha changes and not even an error message.
It kinda works if I change `btn1` and `btn2` event listeners to stage event listeners, but not as I was expecting and has some issues on 2nd loop of flash movie, when those buttons and `MovieClips` are not on the timeline yet.
I'm sure there's a solution for this, just need some help here. Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: Why do you have `stop()` and `play()` in the listeners? You might find that if you just `stop()` somewhere and not play further, the alpha settings might work. Also, check if your clips are properly named in Flash authoring tool.

Comment: Removing stop() and play() wouldnt do the trick neither. And yes, clip names are correct.